# monit - Can I restart a process if system memory is too much?

Tags: monit

I have this rule for system:

```
check system $HOST
    if memory usage > 90% for 3 cycles then alert
```

and this rule for a process:

```
check process my_process matching "..."
    restart program = "..."
```

I would like that if system memory is more than 90% to restart the process `my_process`.

Is this possible with monit?

I tried variants of `if memory usage > 90% for 3 cycles then restart my_process` but always the syntax is not recognized on `monit reload`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Back to your sample, you can use something like this.

```
check system $HOST
  if memory usage > 90% for 3 cycles then 
     exec "/bin/bash -c '/usr/local/bin/monit restart my_process'"
```

To restart a service named "my_process".
With regards, Lutz

Answer (score -1):

The command (start, stop, restart, ...) execute the proper command for the service itself.
With regards,
Lutz

Comment: Thanks but it's not quite answering the question. It is possible to start/stop/restart a service in check service but the question is if it's possible to start/stop/restart a service from a check system.

Comment: You can add a (start, stop, restart, ...) command to any test, but the command execute the proper command for the service itself only. The only way, to execute a command for an other service is the exec statemant. Based on the exec statement you can execute any command/script. Sorry, Lutz

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).